# Loading TableViewDataSource after a method finish

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, ios8

I want to call TableViewData Sources method for Seeting up Ui after it has been fethced from parse . With this i am able to fetch

```
func loadImages() {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "TestClass")
    query.orderByDescending("objectId")


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({(objects:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
        if(error == nil){

            self.getImageData(objects as [PFObject])

        }
        else{
            println("Error in retrieving \(error)")
        }

    })//findObjectsInBackgroundWithblock - end


}

func getImageData(objects: [PFObject]) {

    for object in objects {

        let thumbNail = object["image"] as PFFile

        println(thumbNail)

        thumbNail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
              var imageDic = NSMutableArray()
                self.image1 = UIImage(data:imageData)
                //image object implementation
                self.imageResources.append(self.image1!)


                println(self.image1)

                println(self.imageResources.count)


            }
            }, progressBlock: {(percentDone: CInt )-> Void in

        })//getDataInBackgroundWithBlock - end



    }//for - end


   self.tableView.reloadData()
```

But not able to populate these fetched data to tableview like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    println("in table view")
     println(self.imageResources.count)
    return imageResources.count+1;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:CustomTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell") as CustomTableViewCell

    var (title, image) = items[indexPath.row]

   cell.loadItem(title: title, image: image)


    println("message : going upto this line")
    println(self.imageResources.count)


   var (image1) = imageResources[indexPath.row]

    cell.loadItem1(image1: image1)

return cell
}
```

Then on loaditem i am trying to show up the images and i have writen my own array to populate to the image array but i am geeting a zero value when populating so not able to set it up

Any Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you connect the the delegate/datasource of the tableview with the controller. ie., self.tableview.delegate = self; self.tableview.datasource = self; ?

Comment: Sorry suresh but actually i am not abel to get you as m also a newbie so not able to get it can u please give a more concerte info regarding this?

Comment: Please have look at this link https://gist.github.com/watert/13c38d269ea15aa8360f

Comment: Try calling `your_table_view.reloadData()` when Parse finished to retrieve data.

Comment: @ios i tried calling my own tableview data but still that empty index buffer

Comment: @suresh i tried calling that also but my problem is still the same. can you suggest who to call tableview data source after getImage has completed execution.

Comment: In the controller declaration, add the protocols UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate. ie.,                    class MyTableViewController : UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {  ...... }

Comment: And in the viewDidLoad() method, add the two lines as self.tableView.dataSource = self; self.tableView.delegate = self;

Comment: I have done that only in my viewController i have done lik this class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate 
i want to know how to set the tableview after the func loadImage has finised

Comment: Then, you have add the UITableView as follow,  class MyTableViewController : UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {  var tableView : UITableView!; override func viewDidLoad(){  self.tableView.dataSource = self; self.tableView.delegate = self; ....    }}, refer the github url shared by me.

Comment: i tried that also as mentioned but dint seem to work i wasnt able to resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems, all related to concurrency - your load is occurring in the background and in parallel.

The first problem is the use of `self.image1` as a temporary variable in the loading process - this variable may be accessed concurrently by multiple threads.  You should use a local variable for this purpose.

Second, you are appending to `self.imageResources` from multiple threads, but Swift arrays are not thread safe.

Third, you need to call reload on your tableview after you have finished loading all of the data, which isn't happening now because you call it while the background operations are still taking place.

Finally, your `getImageData` function is executing on a background queue, and you must perform UI operations (such as reloading a table) on the main queue.

The simplest option is to change get thumbnail loading to synchronous calls - This means that your thumbnails will load sequentially and may take a bit longer that the multiple parallel tasks but it is easier to manage -

```
func getImageData(objects: [PFObject]) {

    for object in objects {

        let thumbNail = object["image"] as PFFile

        println(thumbNail)

        let imageData? = thumbNail.getData
        if (imageData != nil) {
                let image1 = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                //image object implementation
                self.imageResources.append(image1!)

                println(self.imageResources.count) 
       }

    }//for - end

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   })
}
```

A more sophisticated approach would be to use a dispatch group and keep the parallel image loading.  In order to do this you would need to guard the access to the shared array

Comment: the code you suggested i tried d same but doesnt seem to work in my case

Comment: What is the code for `loadItem` and `loadItem1` In your custom cell class? Can you add it to your question? What do you get in the log now?

Comment: Also why do return count+1 in numberOfRowsInSection?  Have you set a breakpoint to confirm that your table functions are being called?

Comment: func loadItem(#title: String, image: String) {
        backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: image)
        titleLabel.text = title
    }
    func loadItem1(#image1 :UIImage)
    {
        backgroundImage.image=image1
    }
 in loadItem i am loading my own local stored images  
return count+1 was just added for debuging purpose

Comment: and the error i keep on getting is the same from the day i posted this to till dat i.e
fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer